# upload csv file to blob through c# .net and delete it after entering the data into database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage

How can I upload a .csv file into blob and then read it from back-end and delete it after the data is entered into database?

As I am new to this, I don't have much knowledge of it.
I have gone through the azure website and tried their code but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Create your container in Azure and get your AccountName and Access Key to your ur blob Storage.

> Follow this link :
>   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/

Than in your visual studio create a class file and follow code given below :

```
public class BlobStorageService
{
    public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobSetting"]);
        CloudBlobClient blobclient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobcontainer = blobclient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");            
        if (blobcontainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            blobcontainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
        }
        return blobcontainer;
    }

    public string GetReadData(string filename)
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobSetting"]);

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob.csv"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        string text;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
            text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadDevicesToRegister11(HttpPostedFileBase userDetailCsvfile)
{
    BlobStorageService df = new BlobStorageService();

    if (userDetailCsvfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //To upload file on Blob
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = df.GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(userDetailCsvfile.FileName);
        blob.UploadFromStream(userDetailCsvfile.InputStream);

        //To read File from Blob
        blobContainerRead = df.GetReadData(userDetailCsvfile.FileName);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Explanation bro......I got it ...I had a problem with the container...

Comment: So... how do you delete?